# Awk using index with Substring

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have one command to cut string.

I wonder detail of control index of command in Linux "awk"

I have two different case.

I want to get word "Test" in below example string.

```
1. "Test-01-02-03"    
2. "01-02-03-Test-Ref1-Ref2
```

First one I can get like

```
substr('Test-01-02-03',0,index('Test-01-02-03',"-"))
-> Then it will bring result only "test"
```

How about Second case I am not sure how can I get Test in that case using index function.

Do you have any idea about this using awk?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know where in the dash-separated string the "test" word will occur?

Comment: Are you looking for a specific word (like "Test") all the time? Just that specific set of characters between `-` (or at the start or end of the word)?

Comment: @glennjackman Yes rule is a same ~ Every time. same location but could be different words (Not only Test) but location is same every time !

Comment: @EtanReisner words sould be changed but location is same

Comment: So you are looking for the field at a given location in the string? Where fields are split by `-`?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yeaah from the end after two "-" split by - then I want to get that value.

Comment: @clear.choi, your sample text shows they are NOT in the same place (#1 is 4th from end, #2 is 3rd from end)

Comment: You're asking us how to implement what you think is the right solution to your problem, but it sounds very much like this is not a good solution for any problem. I mean you are searching for the word `Test` and then printing that same word for every line [where it is found]. Unlike searching for and printing a string that matches an RE, it makes no sense to use index/substr to find and print a string vs eg `/Test/{print "Test")`. If you explain WHAT you are trying to do instead of HOW you think it should be done, we can better help you. Provide a few lines of sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how to use index() to find/print a substring:

```
$ cat file
Test-01-02-03
01-02-03-Test-Ref1-Ref2

$ awk -v tgt="Test" 's=index($0,tgt){print substr($0,s,length(tgt))}' file
Test
Test
```

but that may not be the best solution for whatever your actual problem is.

For comparison here's how to do the equivalent with match() for an RE:

```
$ awk -v tgt="Test" 'match($0,tgt){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file
Test
Test
```

and if you like the `match()` synopsis, here's how to write your own function to do it for strings:

```
awk -v tgt="Test" '
function strmatch(source,target) {
    SSTART  = index(source,target)
    SLENGTH = length(target)
    return SSTART
}

strmatch($0,tgt){print substr($0,SSTART,SLENGTH)}
' file
```

Answer (score 3):

If these lines are the direct input to `awk` then the following work:

- `echo 'Test-01-02-03' | awk -F- '{print $1}'` # First field
- `echo '01-02-03-Test-Ref1-Ref2' | awk -F- '{print $NF-2}'` # Third field from the end.

If these lines are pulled out of a larger line in an awk script and need to be split again then the following snippets will do that:

- `str="Test-01-02-03"; split(str, a, /-/); print a[1]`
- `str="01-02-03-Test-Ref1-Ref2"; numfields=split(str, a, /-/); print a[numfields-2]`